# How to alter formatting of \footref in the memoir class?

Tags: footnotes, memoir

The memoir class has a nice function called `\footref` for labeling a footnote so you can later refer to its number. Here's a minimal example:

```
\documentclass{memoir}
\begin{document}

Omnis rerum autem pariatur commodi consequatur corporis libero. Qui magni
voluptatum nulla. Doloremque\footnote{This is an interesting
word.\label{fn:interesting}} libero error expedita et.

Sit ad aspernatur aliquam enim delectus eaque. Sit pariatur qui eaque fuga
quod\footnote{This footnote is between the others.} nihil adipisci. Et
voluptatem eos omnis velit ducimus hic reprehenderit repellat. Repellendus sit
ab quae. Consequatur sint qui quia.

Dolorum et accusantium et mollitia dolores. Omnis officia culpa provident.
Distinctio dolorum laboriosam ad soluta laboriosam dolore optio in. Distinctio
incidunt eveniet soluta voluptatem repudiandae nostrum qui deserunt. Non
doloremque\footnote{See note \footref{fn:interesting}.} soluta consequatur
debitis nostrum amet animi. Quis possimus eum iure omnis.

\end{document}
```

This produces the following:

[image: footnote picture]

This is very useful for cross-references but I don't like the way it produces a superscript number. I would like to change it so that the number "1" in "See note 1" is normal text size. However, I've been unable to work out how to do that.

Comment: you can use `\ref{fn:interesting}`.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The `footref` macro prints its argument as though it was at the start of a foot note. Just change your `\footref` to an ordinary `\ref`

```
... doloremque\footnote{See note \ref{fn:interesting}} ...
```

and you should get what you want.

Comment: Brilliant! And so easy. I had been misled by the general warnings against using 'normal' labels and references in footnotes and had assumed I'd need to redefine footref in some way... Thanks!